# Troubles Prepositioning Node Using Coordinate System Conversions

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit, coordinates, coordinate-systems

Okay so I have been trying to preposition a sprite node before adding it to the scene. The only problem is that I need to know the (0, 0.5) or (left, middle) position of the node, in scene coordinates before I can position it properly.

I know about the convertPoint:(CGPoint) toNode/fromNode:(SKSpriteNode *) methods and currently I have worked out the following **within the Scene's** code:

```
[node convertPoint:CGPointMake(0,0.5) toNode: self]
```

I also wasn't sure if it was confusing self (the scene) with self (the node), so I tried

```
SKScene *scene = self;
[node convertPoint:CGPointMake(0,0.5) toNode: scene]
```

I am pretty sure that I didn't have to make the distinction but I tried any ways.

The logged result of both attempts was **(0,0.5)**.

The node.position is **(50, 100)**.

In case the above is not clear, I am  trying to find the position on the edge of the frame, which should be equal to the nodes width. The reason why I am not using width though is because I am placing it in respect to another node and the two nodes may be rotated.

The theories I am trying to reference are from [Apples Spritekit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Art/cartesian_coords_2x.pnghttps://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Art/cartesian_coords_2x.pnghttps://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Art/cartesian_coords_2x.png)

If there is an easier way to establish a distance between two nodes based on the width of one node, taking into account rotation, feel free to post it for I would love to know, although I still need the node conversion for other methods.

Thank you in advance for all of your help.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want, but convertPoint:toNode: gets absolute position, not relative like 0,0.5. Check if CGRectGetMinX and CGRectGetMidY help in what you are looking for.

Comment: I did find a way to use CGRectGetMinX, and CGRectGtMidY to do so, but it seemed very clunky. I know that when you set an anchor point you set it using (0.5,0.5) as the default centre and (0,0) for the bottom left. Knowing this I discovered that by setting the anchor point to (0,0.5) and then checking the nodes position would give me exactly what I need. The only problem is every time I set the anchor point to that position I have problems with the physics bodies.

Comment: Replying on the answer since I'm adding code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't change the anchor point once the node has been added as it will inherently change its position. If you are using anchor 0.5, 0.5 to rotate the nodes leave it like that. If you want to get the maxX point from a rotated node you could do something like this:

```
    SKSpriteNode *sprite2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor blackColor] size:CGSizeMake(50, 50)];
    float angle = - sprite.zRotation;
    CGPoint dirVect = CGPointMake(cosf(angle), sinf(angle));
    CGFloat distance = sprite.frame.size.width/2 + sprite2.frame.size.width/2;
    CGPoint destPoint = CGPointMake(sprite.position.x + (dirVect.x * distance),
                                    sprite.position.y + (dirVect.y * distance));


    sprite2.position = destPoint;
    [self addChild:sprite2];
```

Where sprite is the node you have rotated and sprite2 the node you want to add respect of the first node. distance should be the distance (excuse the pun) between the anchor points of the two nodes.

Let me know if this is what you are looking for. If not, a screenshot would help :)

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to get back to you. I just want to say that the code you supplied is brilliant. If you could just explain one thing to me that would be great. The dirVect variable uses the cosine and the sine of the angle. It works, as this makes the new object appear directly beside the the first object, I just don't understand how or if cos is specific for x and sin is specific for y. There is just one other thing. When I rotate the first sprite (by 90 degrees or 0.5 PI) they align perfectly. What should I do if I want sprite2 to have the same zRotation as sprite1? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that will give you the X and Y cords of the direction vector with that angle considering an angle of 0 is (1,0). Then it depends "where" do you want it to point based on the rotation of your object.

As for 2nd question: if both sprites have an anchor of (0.5,0.5) they can have same rotation. But note that, if you want them perfectly aligned, you may have to vary distance depending on the rotation if "sprite1" is not a circle.

Comment: Also, depending on what you are trying to achieve, if you are planing to update the position of sprite2 while moving sprite1 you might find easier to add sprite2 as a child of sprite1 so that sprite2 will maintain its relative position when moving sprite1...